# Android Things: 5.1

Tags: android, android-things

**meminfo** used to work in Android Things DP 4.0, but it doesn't appear to be functional in Android Things DP 5.1 (OIR1.170720.017).

Any suggestions on getting memory usage?

I have a PICO-IMX6UL-KIT.
https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx6ul.html

```
$ adb shell uname -a
Linux localhost 4.1.33-06697-g59c7fe0c8372 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 18 02:48:05 UTC 2017 armv7l

things_5.1]$ adb shell dumpsys meminfo

*** SERVICE 'meminfo' DUMP TIMEOUT (10s) EXPIRED ***
```

Comment: Please file a bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192720&template=847005

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65383564

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in the latest **Android Things DP6** release.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65383564) they will re-open to examine.